# I keep getting this error: passing arg 1 of `shuffle' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

So I'm working on this deck program, and now that I've got almost everything working I just need to make a shuffling function. but when I try to I keep getting the error in the title

To keep it short I'll just post the function, but basically I just need to print the deck once (which works) then shuffle the deck in a function and return the shuffled deck and print it again (now shuffled).

I don't understand why I'm getting this error cause I'm only working with one variable type. If I could get some help that would be nice.

here is the relevant code:

```
int shuffle(int deck[52]); /*Function Prototype*/

int main()
{
     int deck[52], i, n;


     shuffle(deck[52]);  /* Function Call */ 

}

int shuffle(int deck[52])
{
srand(52);

deck[52] = rand();

printf("The deck has been shuffled");

return deck[52];
}
```

Comment: Because you are using `shuffle(deck[52]);  /* Function Call */`. You are telling it to pass the 52th element of `deck[]` to `shuffle()`.
Note: You have a lot of other problems in your code as well. So this is just the first one. But keep plugging away! We were all there at one time, when we were learning c.

Answer (score 1):

`shuffle(deck[52])` takes the 53rd element of the array `deck` and passes that to `shuffle`.  Try `shuffle(deck)` instead.

Also note that C arrays are zero based so valid indexes are [0..51].  `deck[52]` is beyond the end of your array; reading or writing to it results in undefined behaviour, including over-writing memory for other variables or crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are zero based in C languages, so desk[52] is one beyond the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

1. shuffle(deck[52])---> by this you are passing address of 53rd element of deck 
   (you can see that from 2:5: note: expected 'int *' but argument is of type 'int')
2. if you want to send full array just pass the array name as function parameter 
   eg. shuffle(deck)

   regards Hims